# Access remote service using GWTP Rest Dispatch

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, gwt-platform

I want to separate packages for UI and backend development of my GWTP app. 
Currently my UI access the backend using Rest dispatch configured like this:

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(RestApplicationPath.class).to("/MyProject/api");
```

I want to access remote service using localhost UI (running GWT app using eclipse plugin). I changed the above line to:

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith(RestApplicationPath.class).to("http://my-app.appspot.com/MyProject/api");
```

Using this, call successfully reaches server ( I can see this in appengine logs) but UI  always gets back status code 0.

What is wrong with above setup? Do I have to do something else to access remote service using GWT ui ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a solution that works both on localhost/App Engine, you'd want to use something like this:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.inject.client.AbstractGinModule;
import com.google.inject.Provides;
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.RestApplicationPath;
import com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.gin.RestDispatchAsyncModule;

public class ServiceModule extends AbstractGinModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        install(new RestDispatchAsyncModule.Builder().build());
    }

    @Provides
    @RestApplicationPath
    String getApplicationPath() {
        String baseUrl = GWT.getHostPageBaseURL();
        if (baseUrl.endsWith("/")) {
            baseUrl = baseUrl.substring(0, baseUrl.length() - 1);
        }

        return baseUrl + "/MyProject/api";
    }
}
```

The string returned by `getApplicationPath` will be bound to `@RestApplicationPath` and used seamlessly by GWTP's RestDispatch.

In your case, the string will resolve to `http://localhost:8080/MyProject/api` or `"http://my-app.appspot.com/MyProject/api"` depending on the app running locally or on App Engine.

Comment: My app works fine (both appengine and localhost) using "bindConstant().annotatedWith(RestApplicationPath.class).to("/MyProject/api");" setting. I want to run UI on desktop (localhost) and access service running on app-engine machines.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. What's the status code returned by the server? I understand that your GWT app receives a status 0, but is it the actual HTTP code that is responded by your GAE App? If per example your server responds with 200 OK, and your GWT app interprets the response as code 0, then it might be another problem.

Comment: The problem was that CORS was not enabled correctly. See this thread for details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwt-platform/RrSOBeaqcEc